# ViewWithTag no longer works as of iOS 8? with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios8

I've just downloaded the new Xcode GM and, after working through a ton of errors, have gotten, my swift project to work perfectly (yay!). However today i tried to install the app on a iOS 8 device, and now all my table and collection views break the app. The trouble comes from something like this :

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionCellCB", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

var pic = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10) as UIImageView
pic.image = DisplayImage;
```

I have double-checked my storyboards to makes sure i have a cell with that reuse identifier and a uiimage view with that tag, but it will not work, both here and on other scenes. 
it works just fine on my iOS 7 device, but breaks everytime on iOS 8. I'm hoping this is a bug, but i can't be certain. Anyone else getting this problem or know how to fix it?

The Main Problem is that when i call viewWithTag the function is returning nil instead of the reference to the view like it did in iOS 7 and previous.

Comment: Define "breaks every time"  Where does it "break"?  Missing a lot of relevant and necessary information.

Comment: it "breaks" when the tableview, or collection view is loaded/reloaded, Like in the  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same problem. Some cells are not showing any content is iOS8. The subviews are not being returned by `viewWithTag`.

It appears to be that the cell is not being created properly and the subviews do not exist. Below is the content of two cells with different identifiers - the first is broken, the second is working:

```
(lldb) po [cell recursiveDescription]
<tSettingsViewCell: 0x7a5d7950; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 695 44); text = 'WiFi'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a5d7af0>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7a5d77f0; frame = (15 43; 680 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x7a5d8500>>

(lldb) po [cell recursiveDescription]
<tSettingsViewCell: 0x7a430210; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 695 44); text = 'Server'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a4301e0>>
   | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7a430170; frame = (0 0; 669 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7a429850>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a430140>>
   |    | <UITableViewLabel: 0x7a430080; frame = (15 0; 645 44); text = 'Server'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7a430030>>
   |    | <UITextField: 0x7a42f980; frame = (495 8; 185 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 200; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a42fce0>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7a42ad10; frame = (15 43; 680 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x7a42aad0>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7a42a870; frame = (677 16; 8 13); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a42a840>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7a4295a0; frame = (0 0; 8 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a429660>>
```

The storyboard is not using auto-layout.

I haven't figured out why this is occurring.

EDIT:

Turns out the custom cell was filtering out the top separator view (not adding it to the subviews) and this seemed to break things. When all subviews were passed to super in addSubview:(UIView*)view, it started working again. Still very mysterious...

Comment: Yeah the only way i got around it so far, is by making the cells a subclass of table/collection viewcells, and assigning iboutlets, thru interface builder.  it's a work around that didn't require me to redesign the actual cells in IB, but i was avoiding it, as i have like 5-6 tables i had to do it for, and i thought, maybe wrongly, thats viewwithtag was the more prefered method.